# NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected while instantiating a provider / NG0203:

Tags: angular, frontend, circular-dependency, ngx-cookie-service

I'm currently working on a login component in my Angular front-end. I get this error upon clicking towards the button that navigates to the `LoginComponent`:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:731:15)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:744:60)
    at Object._class_Factory [as factory] (ngx-cookie-service.mjs:197:84)
    at core.mjs:9412:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:694:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9411:17)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9281:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:13981:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:4484:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:4532:12)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10715:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10715:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:11028:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
```

When i click the button once more i get this error:

```
core.mjs:10572 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for CookieService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for CookieService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.mjs:228:11)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9406:13)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9281:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:13981:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:4484:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:4532:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11764:19)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.LoginComponent_Factory [as factory] (login.component.ts:12:28)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:4738:44)
    at createRootComponent (core.mjs:14236:35)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10715:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10715:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:11028:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
```

This is my login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginRequest } from 'src/models/login-request.model';
import { AuthService } from 'src/services/auth.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  model: LoginRequest;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private router: Router) {
    this.model = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  onFormSubmit(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.model)
    .subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        //Set auth cookie
        this.cookieService.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${response.token}`,
        undefined, '/', undefined, true, 'Strict');

        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I already know that the problem is coming from the "private CookieService: Cookieservice" which i inject in the constructor. And apparently it detects a ciruclar DI while this is the only place i am currently using it. I've had this problem before when injecting the authservice, but adding it HttpClientModule to my app.module.ts fixed that for me. When i try the same thing with this problem it doesn't fix it for me and shows a red squigly line. Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header/header.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my auth.service.ts just to make this complete:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginRequest } from 'src/models/login-request.model';
import { LoginResponse } from 'src/models/login-response.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
  login(request: LoginRequest): Observable<LoginResponse> {
    return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/auth/login`, {
      email: request.email,
      password: request.password
    });
  }
}
```

At last I'm using this as CookieService: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

I tried adding cookieservice to app.module. I expected it to fix the circular DI

Comment: Where are you registering that service for injection?

Comment: in the login.component.ts inside the constructor. second injection.

Comment: That's where you're injecting it.  You need to tell angular somewhere *what* it is allowed to inject.  If you look at the cookie service documentation it describes how to do that as a standalone component (adding it as a provider in the `@Component` declaration) or, if you go back to versions prior to angular 14, adding it in module's `providers` list

Comment: @possum Shouldn't be necessary. But perhaps the `CookieService` isn't a singleton service (aka `providedIn: 'root'`)

Comment: No the [`CookieService`](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/blob/master/projects/ngx-cookie-service/src/lib/cookie.service.ts) seems to be a singleton service. But the [docs]("Usage"
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service#:~:text=ngx%2Dcookie%2Dservice-,Usage,-Add%20the%20cookie) seem to suggest you add the service to the `providers` array either in the component or module

Comment: @Pieterjan Verbatim from the angular docs https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services. "You must register at least one provider of any service you are going to use. The provider can be part of the service's own metadata, making that service available everywhere, or you can register providers with specific modules or components."

Comment: I was able to get rid of the second error by adding CookieService as provide in app.module.ts and add it as provider in the LoginComponent @component.
Now i just have the first error left.